# Turn geometry column into lat/long columns in Geodataframe

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have a Geodataframe with a 'geometry' column in which I have point geometries, e.g. POINT (-0.01334 51.52883). I need to extract the latitude and longitude and add it as new columns in the dataframe.

I tried using

```
df['lon'] = df['geometry'].x
df['lat'] = df['geometry'].y
```

but it gives me a SettingWithCopyWarning and I'm not sure why. Can anybody help please? Thank you!

Comment: This code is okay, there is some code before causing the warning as you are probably working with slice of original df or something.

Comment: Thanks! I've never received the warning before so not sure how or why it occurs - is there a straightforward way to see which part of the code may have caused it? I had to filter out some rows from the original dataframe using df[df['column']=='value']

Comment: Ok so I managed to get around it by dropping the rows I don't want instead of taking a slice of the rows that I do want to keep. The code now works. Thanks for directing my focus on that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't with the code posted - it was to do with slicing the original dataframe several times prior to running this code, as per the comment by martinfleis. I avoided the SettingWithCopyWarning by dropping rows I didn't need from the original dataframe rather than slicing.

Answer (score 6):

You can try directly apply the lan/lon extraction to the df like this:

```
df['lon'] = df.geometry.apply(lambda p: p.x)
df['lat'] = df.geometry.apply(lambda p: p.y)
```

Answer (score 3):

I did this way and had no issue:

```
df['lon'] = df['geometry'].x
df['lat'] = df['geometry'].y
```

and selected the two columns created:

```
df = df[['lon','lat']]
df.dropna()
```

Answer (score -1):

Considering that the values are string in the format described `(lat lon)` you can replace the parenthesis first to better view.

1. `df["geo"] = df["geo"].str.replace(r"[\(\)", "")`
   [image]

After that, you can split by the space char in the middle and expand the columns. [str.split doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

2. `df = df["geo"].str.split(" ", expand=True)`

   [image: str.split]

You'll end up with two columns 0 and 1, just need to rename them after that.

Comment: "geometry" column contains shapely.geometry.Point, not string.